# Vertical alignment UIBarBarButtonItem (back button)

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to move the back button vertically a bit up? I tried doing so using the following line:

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: 30), for: .default)
```

Except it does not seem to do anything to the button.

I also tried updating the `imageEdgeInsets`, but this just crashed the application inside AppDelegate:

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The only elegant way to achieve what you're looking for is to roll a `UIBarButtonItem` with a custom view (which may be a `UIButton` subclass). Documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarbuttonitem/1617151-init).